# Merge different type maps into one in Java 8

Tags: lambda, java-8, java-stream

There are two maps

- `<Integer,String> map1` which is `<ID,Question>`
- `<Integer,String> map2` which is `<ID,Answer>`

I want to merge them into a single map `<String,String> resultMap` which is `<Question,Answer>` such that the Key in this map is the value from map1(Question) and value in resultMap is value from map2(Answer) and this is based on the same ID.

I can do this easily in java 6 as seen in below code.

```
for(Map.Entry<Integer,String> entry:map1.entrySet()){
    qaMap.put(entry.getValue(),map2.get(entry.getKey()));
}
```

But I want to write this in Java 8 using streams and lambdas. How to do that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well assuming your keys(IDs) are the same in both the maps we can do something like

```
Map<String,String> map = map1.keySet().stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(map1::get, map2::get));
```

- In the above statement, `map1.keySet().stream()` will get you a stream of IDs.
- Then `collect(Collectors.toMap(map1::get, map2::get)` will create a Map from the stream of IDs with key as `map1.get(id)` (i.e. your question) and value as `map2.get(id)` (i.e. your answer) for each id.

Answer (score 4):

@above solution is elegant  But someone should give alternative solution which should beginner to understand . So I could go with `foreach` and `lambda`.
You can iterate through Each `map1` and add to the `qaMap`.

```
Map<Integer,String> map1 = new HashMap<>();
Map<Integer,String> map2 = new HashMap<>();
Map<String,String> qaMap = new HashMap<>();
map1.put(1,"what is your age");
map2.put(1,"25");

map1.forEach((k,v)->qaMap.put(v,map2.get(k)));
System.out.println(qaMap.size());
```